# How to hide a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide a div using Javascript. Below is my div.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog-message" class="ui-dialog-title"> </span>
<a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I tried below javascript, but didnt work.

```
   $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css('display','none');
```

Any idea?

Comment: wrap it in document.ready . Also you can simply use $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide()

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide() ;});

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee: hide it with ID, check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

That's not javascript, but jQuery:

You can simply use hide() method:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); // you can also use css() method as yours
```

And you need to wrap your code inside ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
});
```

---

You can learn more about jQuery [here](http://learn.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 2):

you have so many ways

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").fadeOut();
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css('display','none !important');
```

Comment: important is not needed as this will aply css inline and it has highest priority

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  `!important` has highest priority. inline styles will not override `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `document.ready()`:

```
$(function(){

 $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('display','none');

})
```

and you can also use `hide()`:

```
$(function(){

     $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();

})
```

### FIDDLE EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/qcfdLjr3/

Answer (score 1):

ideally hiding with ID would be more flexible way.

```
  <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" id="hidingDiv">
        <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog-message" class="ui-dialog-title"></span>
        <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

JS code for hiding:-

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hidingDiv").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use you own code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css('display','none');
```

or `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();`
    });

because before doing all there document should be ready.